# Do triggers run just by virtue of having those specified function names?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I thought that things like onFormSubmit and onOpen trigger automatically at those events just by virtue of having those function names. But that doesn't seem to be happening. Did I understand that wrong? And if so, what's the point of these reserved functions? Can't any function be set up to trigger when a form is submitted or what have you? I'm confused.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but you do have to set up trigger first (unlike the way Excel VBA behaves if you happen to be coming form there...). Look to the left of the coding screen in GAS. Or youtube it.

Comment: But... you just repeated my confusion. If you need to manually set up the trigger first in the triggers section, why is there such a thing as the onFormSubmit function? How is it different from any other function that you call whatever you want and set to be triggered in the triggers screen?

Comment: You are just setting up that function to actually fire away. Insert whatever you want to happen within that reserved name function. I found an example on youtube within 15 seconds of searching, "setting up trigger in google app scripts"

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly just having a function named onFormSubmit won't automatically fire when a form is submitted - I still have to install a trigger somehow. Right?

Comment: With simple triggers the handler function name is already created.  With installable triggers  you have to create them and assign them to a handler.  If you create an installable trigger that has the same name as the handler for a simple trigger then your functioin will receive two triggers.

Comment: I'm still missing something. I thought what we were saying is if you have a function called onOpen, it will fire when the sheet opens, and you don't need to go to the triggers page to set that up first. Is that right? Because that's not happening for me. I have an onOpen function, but it doesn't fire when I open the sheet. It works fine if I create a trigger to fire the function when the sheet opens. Am I not getting it? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of triggers:

1. Simple and
2. Installable.

> I thought that things like onFormSubmit and onOpen trigger automatically at those events just by virtue of having those function names.

That is correct. Things that run by virtue of the function name are simple triggers and they have multiple restrictions-like they can't run more than 30 seconds. However, there's no `onFormSubmit` simple trigger(see below)

> But that doesn't seem to be happening.

You need to figure out why that "seems" to be so or what made you come to that conclusion. The executions would show why a function failed to execute, when they are triggered.

> Did I understand that wrong?

No. You understood correctly.

> Can't any function be set up to trigger when a form is submitted or what have you?

Yes, Triggers set up this way would be installable triggers. The restrictions here are pretty lax than the simple triggers - like they can run for 6 minutes or if you have workspace account, 30 minutes.

##### To read:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers

*Do note that Form submit is only available as a installable trigger. See the table in the  above link to know what type(s) of triggers are available for which application.*

Answer (score 0):

To setup a trigger for a form (and most any other items).

Create a function that captures the form submission like such:

```js
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

//Constants
  const thisForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();


/**
 * Executed when new entry received. Must setup trigger
 */
function entryMade(e) {
  //This will be your event function
  yourFunction(e.response);
}

function yourFunction(aResponse){
  //whatever your code is...
  thisForm.setDescription("test123"); // form description will change

}
```

To setup trigger...
[image]

Then click on plus in bottom corner to create, and you'll see a screen and put these parameters.

[image]

It will ask for your approval to install your own app. With the `onlycurrentdoc` parameter (which you may want to remove), it shouldn't be aggressively cautioning from allowing.

Once approved, your entryMade function will always execute when a submission comes in and the variable can get passed to `yourFunction`